# Errors while opening SharePoint Online Management Shell

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, pnp-powershell

Whenever I open SharePoint Online Management Shell on windows 10 I get bellow error. Kindly help somebody to resolve it.

**Please note, I am using windows 10 Version 1803(OS Build 17134.112) 64 bit and Management Shell 64 bit**

Please help me.

[image]

**My event log**

[image]
[image]

Comment: Are you running as Administrator?

Comment: You don't need to run the shell as admin.

Comment: Yes, I am running as admin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution for my issue, this error is thrown when you have script execution disabled on the system.

just run the command to unrestrict it and the error goes away.

> Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned

Source :- https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176961.aspx

Hope it will help somebody.

Answer (score 0):

It's tough to say what the root cause could be, but because you're seeing cert validation issues, it will likely come down to the computer clock is wrong, someone has removed the root cert from Windows which the shell leverages, or revocation checking on the system is disabled.

Comment: Than how can we solve it !!

Comment: I can't tell you exactly what the issue is with the provided information. Have you checked your computer clock to verify it has the correct time? You could always investigate the CAPI2 log in the Event Viewer to see what might be going on.

You're going to have to put some effort into this to investigate. The information you're provided as-is is not enough to determine a root cause and solution. I gave you suggestions to look at to start with.

Comment: My computer time is absolutely correct and now I am checking event logs

Comment: I update original question with event log, log I could not understand at all :(

Comment: That does not look like the CAPI2 Event Log. Application Log isn't going to capture certificate errors like this.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance. Now I enable my CAPI2 logs and updated it